# Spring @RequestBody without using a pojo?

Tags: java, spring, gson, pojo

I am using Spring Boot and I have a method defined like this in my controller

```
@PostMapping("/update)
public void update(@RequestBody User user) {
    ...
}
```

However in my post request from client(frontend or postman for example), I have something like this:

```
{
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "id" : 1234,
    "metaInfoId" : "5457sdg26sg4636"
}
```

The thing is my User pojo has only `firstName`, `id` and `lastName` instance fields in it.However in my request I `have to send` `metaInfoId` as well for some other needs. So how can I retrieve or separate `metaInfoId`and `User` model in my controller method above?

Do I have to create another model class called `UserModelRequest` and add all `User` fields along with `metaInfoId` field and then use `@RequestBody`? Is there a way to simply remove `metaInfoId` from the request and then take everything else and dump it into `User` pojo? You could do this easily in nodejs for example(just splice your object and take what you need).

So is there a way to do it in java spring without having to create another model class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can annotate your POJO with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` so the fields that it does not contain are ignored. Ex

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    ... getters & setters ...
}
```

Additionally, you should not include metadata in the body of your rest request. The correct place for this information would be in a headers. This would change your method signature to:

```
@PostMapping("/update)
public void update(@RequestBody User user, @RequestHeader(value="metaInfoId") String metaInfoId) {
    ...
}
```

If you must add the information in the request, then your would need to update the User pojo class to include this field (Or have it extend a class with the metaInfoId field)

Lastly, you really don't want to create a new type. You can change the signature to accept a map and retrieve the necessary info like:

```
@PostMapping("/update)
public void update(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> userMap) {
    String metaInfoId = userMap.get("metaInfoId");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
    final User user = mapper.convertValue(userMap, User.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This solves half of my problem. Now that Pojo ignores unknown properties, I shouldn't get any bind error. However the `metaInfoId` which is part of the request is still important to me. How do I retrieve that value as well in my controller?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the spec. I know its not ideal, but that's how the project is already built and I don't have any say in it to change the way request is sent. So is there no way to do this without creating another pojo or adding extra fields to user pojo? Thanks

Comment: I added one more option for completeness

Comment: Old answer but just to confirm: When I send 2 strings to a controller I only can build a POJO and use [at]RequestBody, or I can use a Map<String, String> also as a [at]RequestBody? But there is no simple way to just say "[at]PostMapping("/foo")
public void foo([at]SomeCoolAnno String varA, [at]SomeCoolAnno String varA)"? I don't want to build POJOs for everytime I just 2 mere strings, and the Map is also rather ugly...

Answer (score 1):

I understand from the question that you may need two cases:

- Send a property in the JSON that does not have a corresponding field in the `User` object. In that case, you need to still use the `User` object with the supplied fields and ignoring the rest that was provided in the JSON
- Send additional properties in the JSON and you still need to capture them in the `User` object *without* defining those extra properties specifically in the object.

I think in both cases, it is better to use Jackson than Gson as it has richer marshaling controls over the objects. Thus, my below solution assumes that you will use Jackson with Spring web - the maven dependency for Jackson is as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**First Case**

In this case, you need Jackson to ignore the `metaInfoId` property when it deserializes the JSON to the `User` object. To achieve this, please add this annotation to the top of your `User` class.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // the rest of the class definition
}
```

**Second Case**

In the second case, you still need to capture the extra properties. I'd suggest adding a *catch all* `HashMap` that accepts the extra undefined properties and you can access it by key/value. To achieve this, you'll need to add the following to your `User` class, or better to create an abstract class that has this code where `User` extends it.

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Map<String, Object> extra;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addExtra(final String key, final Object value){
        this.extra.put(key, value);  
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getExtra() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.extra);
    }

    // the rest of the class definition
}
```

Hope this helps